# A proper way to make React app Multilingual

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-props

I trying to find a way to make my app Multilingual, like for example when the user click on "en" all the app becomes in English and when the user click "de" all the app becomes in German. I'm using react without state management library. is there way to properly implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the most popular internationalization libraries for React

- https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next
- https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Also, if your project is small, or you just want to do it on your own, the simplest way is to store the lang data in a router, e.g. you render the same component on different URLs

```
<Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />  // en is default
<Route path="de/shop" component={Shop} />
```

then inside a component, you get lang variable from the router and conditionally render this or that translation.

What will your lang switcher do - just to navigate you to the same component on a different route, e.g: `/shop` -> `/de/shop`

You can store translations data as plain JS objects in your local files or get from the backend.

Comment: Thank you, I checked react-i18next and I think that's what I was looking for, but there is one thing, when I apply it on something in the state object it doesn't work. like when I save some key value in the state {example: "example"} and then apply it like (this.state.example) it doesn't work at all